Show convergence of $\sqrt N \int (\hat G_m - G)\,\mathrm d(\hat F_n - F)$ to zero in probability
Let $\hat F_n$ be the empirical CDF of a probability measure with CDF $F$. I want to prove that $$\sqrt N \int (\hat G_m - G)\,\mathrm d(\hat F_n - F)$$ converges to zero in probability as $\min(n,m)\rightarrow\infty$, where $N := n + m$, and $\hat G_m$ is the empirical CDF of another probability measure with CDF $G$. My previous idea (see DKW Inequality and convergence in probability) was to use the boundedness of $\hat G_m - G$ together with the DKW inequality. However, I was not able achieve the necessary rate of convergence (see other question for details). Now I am looking for a different approach. But now I'm missing an idea on how to prove the result.
Intuitively, we have that both $\hat G_m\rightarrow G$ and $\hat F_n\rightarrow F$ even almost surely (Glivenko-Cantelli). So I would expect $$\int (\hat G_m - G)\,\mathrm d(\hat F_n - F)$$ to converge to zero in probability. In fact, I could use my earlier approach to show convergence to zero in probability. However, the factor $\sqrt N$ ruins everything. I have the additional assumption that $\frac{n}{N}\rightarrow\lambda$ for some $0<\lambda<1$ as $\min(n,m)\rightarrow 0$.

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be i.i.d. sample with distribution $F$, and
$Y_1,\cdots,Y_m$ be i.i.d. sample with distribution $G$, such that $(X_i,i\ge 1)$
and $(Y_j,j\ge 1)$ are independent. Denote the empirical distributions of
$(X_i,i\ge 1)$ and $(Y_j,j\ge 1)$ by $\hat{F}_n$ and $\hat{G}_m$ respectively.
In the following, we will prove
\begin{equation*}
 \operatorname*{plim}_{m\wedge n\to\infty}\sqrt{n+m}\int (\hat{G}_m-G)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{F}_n-F)=0.  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $\operatorname*{plim} $ denote the limit of convergence in probability,
$m\wedge n=\min(m,n)$.  For simplicity, we assume $F,G$ are the distributions on finite interval $[A,B]$.
Proof Denote
\begin{equation*}
 \alpha_m(t)=\sqrt{m}[\hat{G}_m(t)-G(t)], \qquad \beta_n(t)=\hat{F}_n(t)-F(t).
\end{equation*}
At first, we will prove that
\begin{equation*}
 \operatorname*{plim}_{m\wedge n\to\infty}\sqrt{m}\int^B_A (\hat{G}_m-G)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{F}_n-F)
  =\operatorname*{plim}_{m\wedge n\to\infty}\int^B_A \alpha_m(t)\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t) =0. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Suppose $f$ is a function with finite variation, denote the total variation of $f$ by  $\mathsf{V}f$ or $\mathsf{V}(f)$ , then $\mathsf{V}\beta_n\le 2$.
Also, denote the modulus of continuity of an arbitrary function $x(\cdot)$ on $[A,B]$ by
\begin{equation*}
 w_x(\delta)=w(x,\delta)=\sup_{|s-t|\le \delta}|x(s)-x(t)|, \quad \delta>0.
\end{equation*}
Since the distributions of $\alpha_m$  converge to a distribution of continuous
BB process, hence the distribution family of $\{\alpha_m,m\ge 1\}$ is tight, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{\delta\to0}\varlimsup_{m\to\infty}\mathsf{P}[w(\alpha_m,\delta) >\epsilon]=0, \qquad \forall \epsilon>0.  \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{gather*}
 S(m,\delta,\epsilon)=\{\alpha_m: w(\alpha_m,\delta) \le\epsilon\},\\
 \bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t)=\alpha_m(A+[\tfrac{t-A}{h}]h),\quad t\in[A,B],
\end{gather*}
then
\begin{equation*}
 \|\alpha_m-\bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}\| 
 =\sup_{A\le t\le B} |\alpha_m(t)-\bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t)|
 \le  w(\alpha_m,h), \quad h>0, m\ge 1. 
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
 &\Big|1_{S(m,h,\epsilon/3)}\int^B_A (\alpha_m(t)-\bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t) )\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t) \Big| \\
 &\quad\le 1_{S(m,h,\epsilon/3)}\|\alpha_m-\bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}\| \mathsf{V}(\beta_n)\\
 &\quad< 1_{S(m,h,\epsilon/3)}w(\alpha_m,h)2 <\epsilon, \quad h>0, m\ge 1. 
\end{align*}
\begin{gather*}
 \lim_{h\to0}\limsup_{(m\wedge n)\to\infty} \Big|1_{S(m,h,\epsilon/3)}\int^B_A (\alpha_m(t)-\bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t) )\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t) \Big|=0.\quad \text{a.s.}  \\
 \lim_{h\to0}\limsup_{(m\wedge n)}\mathsf{P}\Big[\Big|1_{S(m,h,\epsilon/3)}\int^B_A (\alpha_m(t)-\bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t) )\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t) \Big|\ge\eta\Big]=0,\quad \forall \eta>0.  \tag{4}
\end{gather*}
Next, using $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{A\le t\le B}|\beta_n(t)|=0$, a.s.,
\begin{align*}
 &\Big|\int_A^B \bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t)\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t)\Big|\\
 &\quad = \Big|\sum_{k=1}^K \bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(kh)[\beta_n((k+1)h)-\beta_n(kh)] \Big|\\
 &\quad\le 2K \sup_{A\le t\le B}|\alpha_m(t)|\sup_{A\le t\le B}|\beta_n(t)| 
 \to 0,   
\end{align*}
where $ K\le \tfrac{B-A}{h} $ is finite. Hence,
\begin{gather*}
 \lim_{h\to0}\limsup_{(m\wedge n)\to\infty} \Big|\int_A^B \bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t)\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t)\Big|=0. \quad \text{a.s.} \\
 \lim_{h\to0}\limsup_{(m\wedge) n\to\infty} \mathsf{P}\Big[\Big|\int_A^B \bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t)\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t)\Big|\ge\eta\Big]=0,\quad \forall \eta>0. \tag{5}
\end{gather*}
Meanwhile,
\begin{align*}
 \Big|\int^B_A \alpha_m&(t)\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t)\Big|  \\
 &\le 1_{S^c(m,h,\epsilon/3)} 
 +\Big|1_{S(m,h,\epsilon/3)}\int^B_A (\alpha_m(t)-\bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t) )\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t) \Big| \\
 &\quad + \Big|\int_A^B \bar{\alpha}_m^{(h)}(t)\,\mathrm{d}\beta_n(t)\Big|\\
 &=(E_3)+(E_4)+(E_5)
\end{align*}
From (3)-(5), get (2), i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
 \operatorname*{plim}_{m\wedge n\to\infty}\sqrt{m}\int^B_A (\hat{G}_m-G)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{F}_n-F) =0. 
\end{equation*}
Next, using integration by part, obtain
\begin{equation*}
 \int^B_A (\hat{G}_m-G)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{F}_n-F) = \int^B_A (\hat{F}_n-F)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{G}_m-G) 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{gather*}
 \operatorname*{plim}_{m\wedge n\to\infty}\sqrt{m}\int^B_A (\hat{F}_n-F)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{G}_m-G)=0,\tag{6}\\
 \operatorname*{plim}_{m\wedge n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int^B_A (\hat{F}_n-F)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{G}_m-G)=0,\tag{7}\\
 \operatorname*{plim}_{m\wedge n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int^B_A (\hat{G}_m-G)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{F}_n-F)=0.\tag{8}
\end{gather*}
Furthermore, since $\sqrt{n+m}\le \sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}$, from (2), (6)-(8), we get
\begin{equation}
\operatorname*{plim}_{m\wedge n\to\infty}\sqrt{n+m}\int_A^B (\hat{G}_m-G)\, \mathrm{d}(\hat{F}_n-F)=0.  \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Let us rewrite the integral. I assume that $\hat F_n$ and $\hat G_m$ are generated by independent samples. Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d. samples with distribution $F$, and $Y_1, \dots, Y_m$ be i.i.d. samples with distribution $G$, such that $(X_i)_i$ and $(Y_j)_j$ are independent. Then
$$ \int (\hat G_m - G) \mathrm d (\hat F_n - F) = \frac 1 n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat G_m-G)(X_i) - \mathbb E[(\hat G_m - G)(X_1) \ | \ (Y_j)_j] \right) . $$
Write $\Delta = \sup |\hat G_m - G|$, which is a random variable which depends on $(Y_j)_j$. Since the family
$$ Z_i = (\hat G_m-G)(X_i) - \mathbb E[(\hat G_m - G)(X_1) \ | \ (Y_j)_j] $$
indexed by $i$ forms, conditionally on $(Y_j)_j$, a family of i.i.d. random variables bounded by $2\Delta$, we can apply Hoeffding’s inequality:
$$ \mathbb P\left( \left|\int (\hat G_m - G) \mathrm d (\hat F_n - F)\right| \geq t \ | \ (Y_j)_j \right) \leq 2 e^{-n \frac{t^2}{8 \Delta^2}} . $$
The Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality states that
$$ \mathbb P(\Delta > s) \leq 2 e^{-2ms^2} . $$
Combining the two, we get
$$ \mathbb P\left( \left|\int (\hat G_m - G) \mathrm d (\hat F_n - F)\right| \geq t \ | \ (Y_j)_j \right) \leq 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-n \frac{t^2}{8 s^2}} \mathrm d P_{\Delta}(s) , $$
where $P_\Delta$ is the distribution of $\Delta$.
Integrating the right-hand side by part (taking $\mathrm d P_\Delta$ as the Stieljes derivative of $-\mathbb P(\Delta>s)$), we get that it equals
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{nt^2}{2s^3} e^{-n\frac{t^2}{8s^2}} \mathbb P(\Delta>s) \mathrm d s \leq \int_0^\infty \frac{nt^2}{s^3} e^{-n\frac{t^2}{8s^2} - 2ms^2} \mathrm d s . $$
With the change of variable $x = s^2 \sqrt{\frac{16m}{nt^2}}$, the integral becomes
$$ 4 \sqrt{mnt^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} e^{- \frac 12 \sqrt{mnt^2} \left( \frac 1 {x} + x\right)} \mathrm d x . $$
Let us split it in two parts: the integral on $(1,\infty)$ is smaller than
$$ 4 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} e^{-\frac 12 \sqrt{mnt^2} x} \sqrt{mnt^2} \mathrm d x \leq 2 mnt^2 e^{-\frac 12 \sqrt{mnt^2}} , $$
while the integral on $(0,1)$ is smaller than (by change of variable $y=1/x$)
$$ 4 \int_1^\infty e^{-\frac 12 \sqrt{mnt^2} y} \sqrt{mnt^2} \mathrm d y \leq 8 e^{-\frac 12 \sqrt{mnt^2}} , $$
thus
$$ \mathbb P\left( \left|\int (\hat G_m - G) \mathrm d (\hat F_n - F)\right| \geq t  \right) \leq 2 (mnt^2 + 4) e^{-\frac t 2 \sqrt{mn}} . $$
It follows that for every $\varepsilon>0$,
$$ \mathbb P\left( \sqrt{N} \left|\int (\hat G_m - G) \mathrm d (\hat F_n - F)\right| \geq \varepsilon \right) \leq 2 \left(\frac{mn}{m+n} \varepsilon^2 + 4 \right) e^{-\frac \varepsilon 2 \sqrt{\frac{mn}{m+n}}} \to 0 $$
as $\min(m,n)\to \infty$, hence the convergence in probability that you desire.
Note. The above computation tells you that $\int (\hat G_m - G)\mathrm d (\hat F_n - F)$ is (at most) of the order of $(mn)^{-1/2}$ with an exponential bound on its tail. In your case, it would be of order $N^{-1}$ and not $N^{-1/2}$. In fact, any sequence $(t_{m,n})$ such that $mnt^2_{m,n} \to +\infty$ would ensure that
$$ \frac{1}{t_{m,n}} \int (\hat G_m - G) \mathrm d (\hat F_n - F) \to 0 $$
in probability; the smaller this sequence, the sharper the bound.

Thanks for your reply. I eventually decided for the other answer (eventhough it was more difficult to understand) as I really liked some aspects of @JGWang's proof. However, I really appreciate your effort, I will reward one of your other replies (as it seems I can't bounty one question twice. Thank you, Thomas!
